# Extension method that works on IEnumerable<T> and IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I want an extension method that works on both my List and IQueryable.  The extension methods below accomplish this, but then if I add another identical extension method, but on a different totally unrelated type I get ambiguous call
compile errors.  Why is that?  Isn't the compiler smart enough to know which extension method works?  I mean, only one of these calls is valid, why can't the compiler tell?  Thanks a lot!

```
class ClassA
{
  public bool IsActive{ get; set;}
}

class ClassB
{
  public bool IsActive { get; set;}
}


// then here are my extensions

public static T IsActive<T>(this T enumerableOrQueryable, bool isActive)
  where T : IEnumerable<ClassA>
{
  return (T)enumerableOrQueryable.Where(x => x.IsActive == isActive);
}

public static T IsActive<T>(this T enumerableOrQueryable, bool isActive)
  where T : IEnumerable<ClassB>
{
  return (T)enumerableOrQueryable.Where(x => x.IsActive == isActive);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use IEnumerable<ClassA> instead of T?

Comment: Note, at a glance those `Where`'s should be `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, or `FirstOrDefault` depending on usage - `Where` is for returning multiple matching elements?

Comment: I can't use IEnumerable<ClassA> because I want them to work for both List<ClassA> and IQueryable<ClassA>.  For example, if I pass IQueryable<ClassA> then I want IQueryable<ClassA> to be the return type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The overload rules don't take account of the constraints on methods that it's considering - it determines which overload is best and *then* validates that the constraints match.

The compiler is exactly following the rules of the C# specification.

Related blog posts:

- [Overloading and generic constraints](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints.aspx) (me)
- [Constraints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx) (Eric Lippert)
- [Evil code - overload resolution workaround](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround.aspx) (me - really nasty stuff, but fun)

EDIT: Note that using an "enumerableOrQueryable" is *always* going to convert your lambda expression to a delegate, not an expression tree. So if you wanted it to perform the logic differently for a database, you'd need a change anyway.

EDIT: Your idea *also* wouldn't work because you wouldn't get the same result type out anyway - if you call `Where` on a `List<string>`, the returned value *isn't* a `List<string>`.

What you *can* do is this, if you can introduce a new interface to be implemented by both ClassA and ClassB:

```
public static IQueryable<T> IsActive<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, bool isActive)
    where T : ICanBeActive
{
    // Lambda converted to an expression tree
    return source.Where(x => x.IsActive == isActive);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> IsActive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    bool isActive) where T : ICanBeActive
{
    // Lambda converted to a delegate
    return source.Where(x => x.IsActive == isActive);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was a fast answer.  I feel stupid now.  So, no way at all to accomplish what I am looking to do unless I want to make sure all my extension methods have distinct names?

Comment: @funGhoul: Well, you could try something along the lines of my "evil code" version, but I'm not sure whether that would help you. To be honest, I suspect you'll find it's clearer using separate names anyway. And I've just thought of something else...

Comment: @funGhoul: See my edit for more issues, and a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll edit my question with what I have to do in case anyone cares.

Comment: Late to the party, but the IQueryable version will not work (at least with EF). T needs to be class as well, otherwise the expression contains a cast that confuses the underlying provider.

Comment: @felipe: Thanks for that - I think I'll let your comment speak for itself rather than editing it into the answer, if that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot resolve ambiguity from the generic constraints. For your case, can't you just do something like this ?

```
public static IEnumerable<ClassA> IsActive(this IEnumerable<ClassA> enumerableOrQueryable, bool isActive)
{
  return enumerableOrQueryable.Where(x => x.IsActive == isActive);
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks.  I do not want to specify IEnumerable<> in the signature because I want the same type that I pass in to passed back.  This method will always return IEnumerable<>

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public interface IActivatable
{
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : IActivatable
{
    public bool IsActive{ get; set;}
}

public class ClassB : IActivatable
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> IsActive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, bool isActive) where T : IActivatable
    {
        return collection.Where(x => x.IsActive == isActive);
    }
}
```